# ActionBar showing in preview but not on device

Tags: android, android-studio

In the `ApplicationManifest` I have:

```
<application android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

And as a style I have:

```
<resources>
    <!-- Base application theme. -->
   <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>

    <style name="FullscreenTheme" parent="android:Theme.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@null</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarStyle">@style/ButtonBar</item>
        <item name="metaButtonBarButtonStyle">@style/ButtonBarButton</item>
    </style>
        <!-- Backward-compatible version of ?android:attr/buttonBarStyle -->
        <style name="ButtonBar">
        <item name="android:paddingLeft">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingTop">5dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingRight">2dp</item>
        <item name="android:paddingBottom">0dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/bottom_bar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- Backward-compatible version of ?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle -->
    <style name="ButtonBarButton" />
</resources>
```

In preview mode, the Actionbar can be seen. However, on my device it is not. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe you are applying `FullscreenTheme` to the activity. `ApplicationManifest` code?

Comment: @AhmadNawaz `FullscreenTheme` is not being used. I deleted it but the Actionbar is still not being show.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change parent theme of "AppTheme" to another one, i.e. "Theme.Holo.Light".

Answer (score 0):

Actually actionbar is there but the menus are not visible

modify your res->menu-> main.xml

```
     <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
```

like this
remove line
**`android:showAsAction="never"`**

Answer (score 0):

My god...
In my case there was two styles.xml - in feature and installed.. both should be the same